# pgvector extension on Google Cloud SQL Postgres

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, pgvector

Google Cloud SQL recently [announced](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/using-pgvector-llms-and-langchain-with-google-cloud-databases) support for Postgres extension pgvector. But it's not available in the list of extensions supported `SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions;`. I'm on version 9.6. What do I need to do to see the extension?

Comment: Did you even read the second chapter of the article?

Comment: @nbk I read the whole article but I'm not sure what you're referring to. There is a section on installation and I know how to install. The problem is it won't show up in the list of available extensions in my DB and installation fails

Comment: Can you elaborate on fails did you get an error? Which be and repeat your steps here

Comment: It doesn't even appear in the list of supported extensions in Google Cloud SQL, so failure is inevitable and less relevant. How do I even make it appear in sql command above would also help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this documentation on [`pgvector` installation](https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector#installation):

> Compile and install the extension (supports Postgres 11+)

It is also mentioned through this [changelog](https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#030-2022-10-15):

> **0.3.0 (2022-10-15)**
>
> - Added support for Postgres `15`
> - Dropped support for Postgres `9.6`

Meaning that the minimun Postgres version should be  at least `11` or higher. I've tried installing the extension using version `9.6` and `10`, both unsuccessful.

If you really want this version to be available, you may either use Postgres version `11` or higher or file this as a feature request through [this link](https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector/issues).

Answer (score 1):

You have to get to the latest cloud sql pg maintenance version.

If you select your instance you can manually update in the maintenance panel.

[image]

Comment: This seemed reasonable but I counted the number of extensions available before and after the upgrade and they are the same. I'm thinking it's not available for my version although there is no mention version limitation in pg extensions page in GCP docs

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see 9.6 as your PG version. You need 11+ https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector#installation